# Is it safe to write to a raw socket if reading using socket.makefile?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm have a socket that I need to read from and write to.

I'm using the file like object returned by `socket.makefile('rb')` to read from the socket.

Is it required to also write to the socket via the file like object or is it safe to write to the raw socket? I don't care about any stlye/readability/etc issues, only if it is incorrect or wrong to do so (I.e. doesn't work or can cause errors)

I know to change to write mode on socket.makefile if this is the case.

Comment: You can use a makefile for reading but not for writing if you want. Just don’t use mix direct and makefile for one direction

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: I can use makefile solely for reading and the raw socket for writing, but I can't use the makefile for reasons and socket.recv too?

Comment: you can’t use the makefile for **reading** and socket.recv too. Since makefile buffers, that would be confusing. If you called makefile.readline and it internally read and buffered beyond the end of the line, a following call to recv would skip the buffered data.